# How to use if statement to compare value from a database in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to change the look of a label when the result from the database is equal a certain word. for instance. In my application when ***full payment*** is made, i want to change the appearance using bootstrap class. similarly, i want to change it when the user is owing.

This is what i did but it seem not to be working.

This is the error am getting `syntax error, unexpected '<'`

```
@if( {{$data -> status}} == "Full Payment"  )

<label class="btn btn-primary">{{$data -> status}}</label>

@endif

@if( {{$data -> status}} == "owing"  )

<label class="btn btn-danger">{{$data -> status}}</label>

@endif
```

how do i change the appearance depending on the results from the database

Comment: Do not add the blade braces inside of the if statement. That's only for when you're not inside a blade function/construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `{{}}` braces when you use blade tags (@), since `PHP` is already parsed inside them. This way when your code gets to first brackets ( `{{` ) it renders them as `<?php`, and you get the syntax error. Change your conditions to this:

```
@if($data->status == "Full Payment"  )
   <label class="btn btn-primary">{{$data->status}}</label>
@endif

@if($data->status == "owing"  )
   <label class="btn btn-danger">{{$data->status}}</label>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

What i would recommend doing if those are the only 2 possible outcomes is:

```
<label class="btn {{ $data->status == 'Full Payment' ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-danger' }}">{{$data -> status}}</label>
```

Comment: Sure, well noted. they are three in my case though

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
@if($data -> status == "Full Payment")
```

And

```
@if($data -> status == "owing")
```